# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure in java 17

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, java-17, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to send get reuest to the server.But i'm always getting  "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" .I'm using openjdk-17.0.1 .

package org.example;

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class HttpsGetWithCustomSSLExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // URL of the API endpoint you want to query
            String apiUrl = "https://192.168.14.193:8050/sample-v1";

            // Load trust store
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            try (FileInputStream trustStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream("store/server.truststore")) {
                trustStore.load(trustStoreInputStream, "WalletPasswd123".toCharArray());
            }

            // Load keystore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            try (FileInputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream("store/server.keystore")) {
                keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, "WalletPasswd123".toCharArray());
            }

            // Create SSL context with custom trust store and keystore
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null)
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "WalletPasswd123".toCharArray())
                    .setProtocol("TLSv1.3")
                    .build();

            // Create a CloseableHttpClient with SSL context
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();

            // Create an HttpGet request
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiUrl);

            // Execute the request
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                // Get the response code
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

                // Read the response content
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println("Response Data: " + responseBody);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error massage I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: Don’t post exception stack traces as pictures. Copy the text, just like you did with the source code.

Comment: Please tell us how you have generated the HTTPS certificate for 192.168.14.193 and what certificates are saved in the used trustStore. Are you sure the used server supports TLS 1.3?

Comment: I created certificates using key tool because I'm using self signed certificates. I put that generated certificate into the trust store. I checked it with the tlsv1.3.But still I'm getting the error.